# Matplotlib returns empty plot

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, spyder

I have this python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

n = 100
x = np.random.randn(n)

def update(curr):
    if curr == n:
        a.event_source.stop()
    plt.cla()
    bins = np.arange(-4,4,0.5)
    plt.hist(x[:curr],bins = bins)
    plt.gca().set_title('Samplng the Normal distribution')
    plt.gca().set_ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.gca().set_xlabel('Value')
    plt.annotate('n = {}'.format(curr), [3,27])

fig = plt.figure()
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval = 100)
```

It should update a plot of the normal distribution every 3 draws, but when I run it, my plot is empty and nothing happens. Do you know why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question is flawless. It updates the plot every 100 milliseconds.

My guess would be the following. The fact that you don't use `plt.show()` here but still see a plot suggests that you are using it in an inline environment. E.g. you may be using Jupyter and (intentionally or not) have activated `%matplotlib inline`. The inline backend does not support animations (that's clear since it only shows a png image of the plot) and thus the solution might be to use a different backend.

If in a jupyter notebook:

- If you want to have the animation inside the notebook, use `%matplotlib notebook`.
- If you want to have the animation inside the notebook *and* use `%matplotlib inline` *and*  have matplotlib 2.1 or higher, you may also use from

  ```
  IPython.display import HTML
  HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
  ```

  to show the animation.
- If you want to have the animation as it's own window, use `%matplotlib tk`.

If running the code as a script:

- Add `plt.show()` at the end of the code.

If running in spyder

- Make sure you're not running the code in the inbuilt IPython console. Instead run it in a new dedicated python console.
  [image]

Comment: I think it was the backend actually, you're right. I changed it to automatic and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `plt.show()` at the end. With this instruction is working to me.